# Explain why the residue is equal to the limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I'm studying for a midterm and my teacher warned this would be a good question to understand for the test.  The problem is, I do not know how to go about explaining it.

Suppose g(x) has a pole of order 2 at the point z. Explain why:

$$\textrm{Res}(g;z)= \lim_{x\to z} \frac{d}{dx}((x-z)^2 g(x))$$

Comment: Do you know (the general form of) Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @Tom If you're going to post so many questions, please pause for a moment and learn how to use LaTeX markup: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have you tried following the proof for the more general theorem?

Comment: This exact question was asked by another use not 1 hour ago, and subsequently deleted.

Comment: Sock puppet? Another new user named "Tom" just asked this exact same question for which I left a comment. That question has now been deleted.

Comment: @mrf Aye. I had edited the markup there. This question has the remnants of my markup style (`\textrm` instead of `\text`, no space between `x` and `\to`, etc.)

Comment: @Arkamis I have flagged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition: $\,g(x)\,$ has a pole of order $\,2\,$ at $\,x=z\,$ iff when we develop $\,g\,$ in a Laurent series around $\,x=z\,$ , we get

$$g(x)=\frac{h(x)}{(x-z)^2}$$

with $\,h(z)\,$ analytic and non-zero in some neighborhood of $\,z\,$ , and then

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(x-z)^2}(a_0+a_1(x-z)+a_2(x-z)^2+\ldots)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left((x-z)^2g(z)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(
a_0+a_1(x-z)+a_2(x-z)^2+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=a_1+2a_2(x-z)+\ldots \xrightarrow[x\to z]{}a_1=Res_{x=z}(g)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ has a pole of order $2$ at $a$, then its Laurent expansion at $a$ looks like
$$
g(z)=\frac{c_{-2}}{(z-a)^2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{z-a}+c_0+c_1(z-a)+\dots\tag{1}
$$
where the residue, the coefficient of $\frac1{z-a}$, is $c_{-1}$.

Multiplying by $(z-a)^2$, we have
$$
(z-a)^2g(z)=c_{-2}+c_{-1}(z-a)+c_0(z-a)^2+c_1(z-a)^3+\dots\tag{2}
$$
Taking the derivative yields
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left((z-a)^2g(z)\right)=c_{-1}+2c_0(z-a)+3c_1(z-a)^2+\dots\tag{3}
$$
Taking the limit gives
$$
\lim_{z\to a}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left((z-a)^2g(z)\right)=c_{-1}\tag{4}
$$
which is again the residue of $g$ at $a$.